# This field is required. Error with ImageField django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I'm getting
`'This field is required'` error while uploading image.
I don't understand why I get this error, my model is very basic, but I don't know why and where I'm getting error. Some help would be appreciated.
My model is:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('User-Posts-Details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

'my views is'

```py
class PostCreateViews(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','img','content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and html code

```html
<div class="blog_list">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="blog_heading">New Post</h2>
        <fieldset class="form-group" id="new">
            {{ form|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Should there always be an image associated with Post? Or are you posting an image and it's saying it's still required?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the other possible answer. Change your form to include files in the POST request:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your model field `img`...

From

```
img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
```

To

```
img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics', null=True, blank=True)
```

And then run...

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

And then rerun your app..

Comment: error - ValueError at /user-posts/
The 'img' attribute has no file associated with it

Comment: Are you applied `/` after `pics`, change from `upload_to='pics'` to `upload_to='pics/'` in upload_to ?

Comment: And again run `makemigrations ` & `migrate`.

Comment: Yup, i think i i didn't put '/' anyway i used  enctype method thnks for help

Comment: Always... Happy Coding :)